# Autodraw Texture2D without writing multiple lines repeatedly

Tags: c#, xna

I have tried to draw `Texture2D`s in a line by adding to the x and y coordinates when it gets to the end of the screen. The `Draw` method doesn't draw multiple sprites it just moves the first one at the speed of 20 instead of drawing one every 20 pixels.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

    // TODO: Add your drawing code here
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.DrawString(GameText, MenuText, new Vector2(325,75), Color.Red);

    do
    {  
        spriteBatch.Draw(EarthGrass, place, Color.White);
        place.X += 20;
    } while (place.X < 800);
    place.X = -20;
    place.Y += 20;
    do
    {                
        int IDBint = IDB.Next(11);
        if (IDBint == 10)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(PooperMachoOre, place, Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(EarthDirt, place, Color.White); 
        }
        place.X += 20; 

    } while (place.X < 800);
    place.X = -20;
    place.Y += 20;
    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine at first glance, even though I barley see do loops these days. I assume you want to STOP drawing after the X position is **more** than 460 pixels, since it starts at 0. So simply flip your `>` to a `<`, you will also need to reset your X position each frame, or else it will start where it left off.

```
do
{
     place.X += 20;
     spriteBatch.Draw(EarthGrass, place, Color.White);
} while (place.X > 460);
place.X = 0;
```

Comment: This worked as I wanted it to. I planned for it to draw a world automatically so that I may add my world generation algorithm later as well as what blocks it will generate.

Comment: And also how does the draw method work when you place it back to 0? if you dont does it update itself with the variable?

Comment: The draw method is called many times per second along with the update method (60 fps usually), each frame you must reset the place, so that the next frame can draw correctly. In XNA you must redraw everything each frame, or else it will be cleared (There are different ways but thats the basics of it)

Comment: now if i want to use a System.Random to choose what sprite to draw it just keeps continuously generating the number and changing the sprites.

Comment: I will update the code in the original post to my current draw method

Comment: @DattManiels If the original problem from this question has been resolved, you should take the new problem to a new question.

Comment: @DattManiels What Hyper said, as you can see, you are now getting more answers for different reasons on this question. Go ahead and create a new question so you can accept answers for your *different* question.

Comment: Also note, if you are calling `int IDBint = IDB.Next(11);` every frame, it will be different each time. If you want a set number, only calculate it once (ie, the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
do
{                
    int IDBint = IDB.Next(11);
    if (IDBint == 10)
        spriteBatch.Draw(PooperMachoOre, place, Color.White);
    else
        spriteBatch.Draw(EarthDirt, place, Color.White);

    place.X += 20;

} while (place.X < 800);
```

your `Draw` will change all the sequence of images to draw every frame (and as *Cyral* wrote, it happens 60 times per second).
You don't have to call your random generator in the `Draw` method, but you have to set the sequence of textures to draw only once. In the `Initialize`, for example.